# #Bash bc formatting problems

Tags: bash

How to output the floating point that correct to nearest 10th **only if necessary**

```
E.g. 

---------
input: 1.5

output: 1.5

--------
input: 1

output: 1(but not 1.0)

--------
```

I think it is just a simple question for bash but I cannot find out any solution for that.

The code:

```
printf "%.1f" `echo "scale=1;3/2;"|bc`
printf "%.1f" `echo "scale=1;1;"|bc`
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Mantra on stackoverflow is you have to post 3 simple things: 1- What is your question with samples of input and output expected one. 2- What you have tried? 3- What are the conditions to find the output. Please post the same and let us know on same, cheers :)\

Answer (score 0):

bc `scale=1;` works as expected just don't use printf "%.1f" which formats decimal number with 1 fixed number after decimal.

otherwise if variable contains number with 0 to trim with bash expansion and option `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
x=1.0
echo "${x%%?(.)*(0)}"
```